# Regular expression even occurrence of 0s and each 0 followed by at lease one 1

Tags: regex

How do I put this as regular expression:

Allow an *even* number of `0`s and each `0` is *followed* by *at least one *`1`

For at least two `0`s, but not consecutive `0`s, I can do as

```
(1*011*(0+011*))*
```

but that will allow 3 zeros.

Answer (score 2):

If I got you correctly:

```
^1*(01+01+)+$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/gJ4fU7/2)

- `1*` - start with zero or more ones
- `01+` - a zero, followed by one or more ones
- `01+01+` - two of those to make it even
- `()+` - repetition of the entire group, if you want to support 0 as even number (which it is, but I got a connotation from your question that you don't want to), replace `+` with `*`
- `^$` - from the start til the end of the string

Comment: Your RE won't match any strings that begin with `1`  (eg. `10101`), even though the description does not appear to prohibit that.  There's also the question whether "followed by" means "immediately followed by" -- is `0011` valid?

Comment: @ChrisDodd, true, though if that is the case, `1*` can simply be added at the beginning.

Comment: If we add 1* than I guess it won't take string starting with 0 no?

Comment: @Cannon, it would take strings that start with `0`, just wont require it. Chris speculated that from the way the question is asked, `10101` might also be a required match as it has an even number of `0`s, followed by one or more `1`s.

Comment: I see. Yes 10101 should be valid as it has even 0s and no two 0s together. And string length can be any number of digits as long as two conditions satisfy. So I guess it will be (1)*(01+01+)+$